# Error inserting into users table in Node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I got the **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**
in the  *// Error inserting into users table* section. 
What causes this problem? Where should I check? My database has all the mandatory fields. I am using SQL db.

```
function registerUser(rBody) {
    const connection = mysqlConnection
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // First attempt to has user password, and continue on success
        bcrypt.hash(rBody.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
                // Error crypting password
                resolve({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'Error hashing password'
                })
            } else {
                // Build query & insert into users table
                const valuesStr = `(null, "${rBody.email}", "${rBody.firstName}", "${rBody.lastName}", "${hash}", null, 2)`
                const queryString = `INSERT INTO users values${valuesStr}`
                connection.query(queryString, (err, resp) => {
                    if (err) {
                        // Error inserting into users table
                        resolve({
                            success: false,
                            error: err
                        })
                    } else {
                        // User succesfully created
                        resolve({
                            success: true,
                            message: 'User succesfully created',
                            id: resp.insertId
                        })
                    }

                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO users values${valuesStr}` looks like its missing a space between `values` and `${valuesStr}`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** your query to insert into the table does not seem to follow the standard syntaxis. Try

```
const queryString = `INSERT INTO users(name of your columns) VALUES(${valuesStr}`)
```